# Pass a item of list to a object

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having a problem with multithreading where only one thread is successful completed, others are also terminated ( by using future.isdone() to know) but seem to only process half of codes in callable  ,I guess the following code may be the problem.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < threads ; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            callables.add(new MyCallable(companyNameParts.get(i),
                    companyNumberParts.get(i),companySICCodeParts.get(i),frame));
        }
```

Which of the following statements are(is) true:

1.Only the value of companyNameParts.get(i) is passed to the object

2.The whole list of companyNameParts is passed to the object, then the value is got from the list.

3.The reference of the list is passed to the object.

Because I am doing a multithreading project, I tend not to share any data among them to reduce the complexity, maybe this is the place where I accidently share the data somehow? (I mean the  companyNameParts is unintentionally exposed to every thread somehow?)

Any response is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please extend the code snippet to include point where you start execution of the threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** is an answer to all of the questions.

`new MyCallable` receives a reference to an instance of an object stored at companyNameParts collection at position `i`.